# How to manage locally modified versioned file without committing it to Git?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have this annoying problem since I upgraded to Visual Studio to 2015.

There is a batch script in my repository to compile all sources, based on the Visual Studio version. Since I updated it but other users kept VS 2013, I had to change the Visual Studio version in order to compile sources, and now I'm forced to live with the modified script file that pops every time I commit anything.

I tried to stash it, but when I `git stash pop` my changes (that could happen daily) the modified script pops alongside other files.

So I was wondering, is there a way to tell Git to keep a file as it is *for good*?

Comment: Commit it.  Stash is temporal.  Is there a reason that you can't place it into the repository?

Comment: I cannot commit because I have vs2015. Since it's a compile script, if I push my version whoever hasn't my vs version cannot compile sources

Comment: More questions:  why is it in your code base if you can't commit it?  Why are you working with different Visual Studio versions?

Comment: Just to be sure. You had to modify existing versioned script to work with your setup, am I right?

Comment: @Makoto: That file is in the repo because everyone need it to compile the sources of it. We were all supposed to update vs, so I did when I changed my pc, but others don't, they have 2013. These informations aren't necessary, I can't change the situation

Comment: Any particular reason you don't add it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy precisely, and I can't commit it

Comment: @MadaraUchiha what if I added the gitignore, and one day that file needs to be modified?

Comment: Okay, that brings a bit more clarity into this.  In that event, I'm not sure Git can (or should) help you with this; the mandate to update everyone's environment should have come down and it should have been enforced.

Comment: @Phate01 1. gitignore does not affect your working directory, only what git tracks to be added to the repository, you can edit files under ignore, Git just won't see them. 2. You can explicitly add files to be tracked, even if they're under ignore. 3. If you even need to commit that file, just remove it from `.gitignore`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is a broken workflow, that's why you have problems.

I suggest you to use a different workflow, it's actually the same as Visual Studio uses (see bellow).

Basically, you have a **script shared by the whole team**, but you also need to have a **user-specific script**. So change that team-shared script to include a user specific script (only if it exists) and commit the team-shared script.

Then create the user-specific script which will overwrite or redefine the values from the team-shared script you need to change and add this user-specific script to `.gitignore` (and don't commit it!).

This way each member of your team can have his own user-specific configuration without messing with other members of his team. By the way, that's exactly what Visual Studio is doing - `*.sln` is a shared solution configuration and `*.suo` is a user configuration, which shouldn't be committed.

Repository can look like this:

```
repository
  |
  +-- configuration
  +-- user-configuration
```

And team-shared `configuration` like this:

```
default_values_shared_by_team

include_if_exists user-configuration

some_code
...
```

In `user-configuration` you simply change `default_values_shared_by_team` to values you need to have on your setup. If `user-configuration` file doesn't exist, nothing happens, everything works as before, so other team member are not affected.

Comment: This is really a good idea, I will explain it to the git manager. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's not my idea. It's a generally used model or workflow. It's hard to think up anything better. I hope it will help you.